# Is wordpress comment form safe?

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, comments

I have this Wordpress form for comments, it's pretty standard:

```
<form action="http://sitename.com/wp-comments-post.php" target="writeIframe" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form">
    <p class="comment-form-author">
        <label for="author">Your name</label>
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30">
    </p>
    <p class="comment-form-comment">
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="form-submit">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="1" id="comment_post_ID">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
    </p>
</form>
```

It sends the user input data to wp-comments-post.php inside of a hidden iframe. Is this safe out of the box Wordpress or shall I add code to prevent attacks trough my comment form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at using wp_nonce_field().

Here's what WordPress codex says:

A nonce is a "number used once" to help protect URLs and forms from certain types of misuse.

So i'll definitely advice you to take a look at it and use it.
Go to this codex page to know more:

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces#Adding_a_nonce_to_a_form

Do read the Adding a nonce to a form section

Comment: So I shall put the following as the first field in my form like this:

<form method="post">
<?php wp_nonce_field('my_nonce_action', 'my_nonce_name'); ?>
etc.

Comment: Yes, you should also make sure that you are verifying the nonce . You should use this code for verifying your nonce:   if ( 
    ! isset( $_POST['my_nonce_name'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_nonce_name'], 'my_nonce_action' ) 
) {  print 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.'; exit; } else { //your code on success of verification }

Comment: Would this do, at the top of my comments.php file? $retrieved_nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
if (!wp_verify_nonce($retrieved_nonce ) ) die( 'Failed security check' );